# Print file.txt content to turtle window. python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I've been trying to print the content of my .txt file to the turtle window (within the LADDER border) and can't seem to be successful at it. I've tried with multiple command lines, I've tried to put the file in a class and many more. I don't think it is possible to do so. If you have any idea please feel free to help.
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEHvL.png) the image you see is the in game of the space invader. As I said I tried to print the content of my txt file in the ladder column and I'd like the file content to always stay there and not reboot every time I reload the game.

```
#UPDATE SCOREBOARD AT DEATH
if isCollision(player, enemy):
    text = wn.textinput("EYN", "Enter your name:")
    with open("spaceinvaders_score.txt","a") as f:
        f.write(text + " -- Last %s\r\n" % scorestring)
        print()
    break
```

Comment: The code you have just saves the input to a file. To display text on screen: use [`turtle.write()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html#turtle.write)

Comment: It only works to write text but not to import the content of a txt file and display that same file on screen doesn't it ? I've tried already and it doesn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading lines from a file and having turtle write them to the screen is straightforward:

```
import turtle

FONTSIZE = 18
FONT = ('Arial', FONTSIZE, 'normal')

turtle.penup()
turtle.sety(300)

with open("spaceinvaders_score.txt") as file:
    for line in file:
        turtle.write(line.strip(), font=FONT)
        turtle.goto(0, turtle.ycor() - FONTSIZE)

turtle.exitonclick()
```

Adjust it to stay within your ladder box, add the latest high score, etc.